# DRF API design: the best way to create views for logged-in user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a DRF + React app that allows users to label medical data. Need your opinion on my API design

There are 3 models here: User, Annotation and IC (independent component). Each User can make only one Annotation for each IC.

Currently, I made a separate view with implicit user substitution. GET gives me existing annotation for a user or empty JSON if not exists. POST allows me to create/update annotation for a user. URL has the form of `/api/user-annotation-by-ic/1`

```py
class UserAnnotationByIcView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserAnnotationSerializer

    def get(self, request, ic_id):
        try:
            obj = Annotation.objects.get(ic=ic_id, user=request.user)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response({})

    def post(self, request, ic_id):
        create = False
        data = request.data
        data['ic'] = ic_id
        context = {
            'request': self.request,
        }
        try:
            obj = Annotation.objects.get(ic=ic_id, user=request.user)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(obj, data=data, context=context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data, context=context)
            create = True

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        if create:
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

In all tutorials on DRF I see ViewSet CRUD views with filtering feature. Following this approach, I could use URLs like `/api/annotations?user=1&ic=1`. For security reasons, I would have to check that provided user matches to the logged-in user.

So which approach is better? What are the best practices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither approach is necessarily “right” or “wrong,” as it ultimately depends on what works best for your application and development team.

However, in my experience, following a resource-based approach for API design is more maintainable and extendable in the long term. A resource-based approach will also make the API more “REST-ful.”

By “resource-based,” I mean that API endpoints would be structured based on resources, or entities/objects. For example, in your application there could be separate API endpoints for `User`, `Annotation`, and `IC`. The URL routes for these endpoints could be:

- User: `/api/users`
- Annotation: `/api/annotations`
- IC: `/api/ics`

As you have mentioned, the `Annotation` entity could then be queried using an approach similar to:

`api/annotations?user=1&ic=1`

This URL structure enables the endpoint to be more generic and re-usable. It can also be easily extended to add additional filtering and functionality for future use.

On the other hand, structuring the `Annotation` API endpoint as `/api/user-annotation-by-ic/1` is still effective, but it is less generic and re-usable. This endpoint seems to be very specific, and therefore it may only be used for one purpose. When new or different functionality is needed, it will likely need to go in a different endpoint. This will lead to a larger number of endpoints needing to be maintained over time.

Finally, regarding my comment about being more “REST-ful”, this article provides some helpful information about the design of a REST API around resources: https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/.